# How to automatically validate rest parameters in @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to automatically validate `REST` parameters on a spring `REST` service.

I tried it using `@Valid @NotNull`, but the rest request does not get rejected automatically, but the dao method is executed with null argument. Why?

```
@RestController
public class RestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public Boolean getResponse(@Valid @NotNull @Length(max = 20) String username) {
          return daoService.lookup(username); //is executed if username = null
    }
}
```

How can I get automatically a returned HTTP error, eg 400?

Comment: I think you are just missing @RequestBody, although not sure Spring can validate input String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of validation on request parameters..

```
public ResponseEntity<AgencyResource> saveAgency(
    @Valid @RequestBody AgencyResource agencyResource) {
 return new ResponseEntity<AgencyResource>(agencyResource, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

This is from the POST http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: So I neccessairly have to wrap my parameters in a complex object? I thought I could achieve validation also on strings?

Comment: I'm not sure about simple validation on strings via annotaiton. You could also write a custom validator ..kinda like..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544265/spring-3-mvc-request-validation

Comment: you may already know this..but @RequestParam(value = "regNo", required = true)..you can do this..but this as far as iknow only checks for required paramters..not sure if it can do min / max length checks unless u write validators.

Comment: I didn't know this, and probably is great to ensure my method does not get called if params are missing (which is my main requirement).