# Spring method level Validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I want to valid if two arguments of the `getCategories()` fulfill my expectations. I've created a validator:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnvironmentIdValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface IEnvironmentIdValidator {
    String message() default "Invalid environment ID.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String[] value();
}
```

And the implementation:

```
@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class EnvironmentIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IEnvironmentIdValidator,Object[]> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(IEnvironmentIdValidator constraintAnnotation) {
        // logic

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object[] object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
       // logic
    }
}
```

I'm calling this validator at one of my endpoints with annotation, simultaneously passing two parameters.

```
    @IEnvironmentIdValidator(value = {"environmentID", "requestAuthorizationHeader"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCategories(@PathVariable(name = "environmentID") Long environmentID,
                                           @RequestHeader("Authorization") String requestAuthorizationHeader) {
//...
}
```

But unfortunatelly the validator is not being triggered. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831503/how-to-automatically-validate-rest-parameters-in-restcontroller and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544265/spring-3-mvc-request-validation The suggestion on those threads appears is that you'd need to define an object. But you're using PathVariable so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values is more relevant

Answer (score 0):

Your controller must be annotated with @Validated, otherwise your bean will not have attached the custom validation.

```
//...
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Controller
@Validated
public class MyController {

    @IEnvironmentIdValidator
    @GetMapping("/test/{environmentID}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCategories(@PathVariable(name = "environmentID") Long environmentID,
                                      @RequestHeader("Authorization") String requestAuthorizationHeader) {
    //...
```